# Why is my react component not rendering only when using routes? react-router-domV.6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Main from './Pages/Home/Main.js';
import NotFound from './Helpers/NotFound.js';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app-routes">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/">
          <Main />
        </Route>
        <Route>
          <NotFound />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './main.css';

function Main(){
    return (
        <div className="main-content">
            <h1>This is the Main Page</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Main;
```

Definitely not a component import issue tested without routes and works perfectly but when I add routes or even just route by itself nothing will render. I have react-router-dom v.6 installed

Comment: Do you get any error in the console? Check both the browser dev-tools and react-terminal :)

Comment: No errors anywhere, just a white screen loads with no rendered components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React-router v6 api has changed. you need to use element prop to render a component.

```
  <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Main>} />
        <Route path="/custom" element={<div>custom</div>} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />}>
  </Routes>
```

Comment: this is by far the best explanation. I never noticed that even the element prop is being used now. Making this change made my app render. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**react-router-dom@6 uses element property in the route to display the component**

> To display not found page use path ="*" and add it the end of all the
> routes so whenever routes don't match I goes to the not found
> (404)page.

```js
 <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Main />}/>
         //all your routes here 
        <Route path="*" element={ <NotFound />}/> //in the last
        
      </Routes>
```